# How do we print a partially filled Integer array? we can't use '\0' in case of integer

Tags: c

so i am giving a user defined array as an input and then picking out the unique numbers in that array and storing them into a different array but the problem is that there is no way of knowing the size of the new array. if the array is partially filled, it will print a few garbage values.

i have tried using '\0' but later on found out that it can only be used in case of "character array".
next what i tried is using "sizeof" but still no results. "sizeof" is storing the maximum size of the array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int n;
        printf("Enter The Size Of Array: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        int a[n],b[n];
        int i;
        printf("Enter The Elements Of The Array:\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                int j;
                for(j=0;j<i;j++)
                {
                        if(a[i]==a[j])
                        {
                                break;
                        }
                }
                if(j==i)
                {
                        b[j]=a[i];
                }
        }
        printf("\nUnique Numbers Are:  ");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                printf("%d  ",b[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Result:-

```
Enter The Size Of Array: 10
Enter The Elements Of The Array: 5 4 3 1 2 3 5 3 2 4
Unique Numbers Are:  5  4  3  1  2  32627  896  0  -919050752  32767
```

Expected Result:-

```
Enter The Size Of Array: 10
Enter The Elements Of The Array: 5 4 3 1 2 3 5 3 2 4
Unique Numbers Are:  5  4  3  1  2
```

Comment: This is C code? I think you should tag C instead of C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. Use a counter:

```
int main()
{
        int n;
        printf("Enter The Size Of Array: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        int a[n],b[n];
        int i;
        int noDups=0; // Init counter                                                                              
        printf("Enter The Elements Of The Array:\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
                scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
                int j;
                for(j=0;j<i;j++) {
                        if(a[i]==a[j])
                                break;
                }
                if(j==i) {
                        b[j]=a[i];
                        noDups++; // Increment counter                                                             
                }
        }
        printf("\nUnique Numbers Are:  ");
        for(i=0; i<noDups ;i++) { // Loop noDups number of times                                                   
                printf("%d  ",b[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
}
```

But don't forget to check the return value of `scanf`. It's done like this:

```
if(scanf("%d",&a[i]) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error reading integer\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: great! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out one more mistake in the code:-

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
         int n;
         printf("Enter The Size Of Array: ");
         scanf("%d",&n);
         int a[n],b[n];
         int i;
         int p=0;
         printf("Enter The Elements Of The Array:\n");
         for(i=0;i<n;i++)
         {
                 scanf("%d",&a[i]);
         }
         for(i=0;i<n;i++)
         {
                 int j;
                 for(j=0;j<i;j++)
                 {
                         if(a[i]==a[j])
                         {
                                 break;
                         }
                  }
                 if(j==i)
                 {
                         b[p]=a[i];
                         p++;
                 }
         }
         printf("\nUnique Numbers Are:  ");
         for(i=0;i<p;i++)
         {
                 printf("%d  ",b[i]);
         }
         printf("\n");
         return 0;
 }
```

- The Problem was That The Other Array "b[n]" which i was filling by
  taking elements from a[n] wasn't getting filled properly.
- I was using b[j] = a[i] when [j==i]. but j isn't linear in many cases.
- using another variable (which doesn't skip any values starting from 0) to fill the array b[n] should correct the code.